# I want to use a if controller inside a foreach controller inside the same transation controller in JMeter

Tags: json, jmeter, web-api-testing

I have 2 get api's from where I have extracted a variable using json extractor, from one api I have extracted title and from other similar api I have extracted titles. This title and titles are folder names present in that api.

The first api has values of title as: {apple, pineapple, blue berry, cherry}

The second api has values of titles as : {apple, blue berry, cherry, pineapple, kiwi}

I want to check a condition using if controller, only if the both the title and titles and title are same it should move to the next controller to do further operations. This if controller is inside a foreach controller.

So in the if controller I have used the condition as:

${__jexl3("${title_ALL}"=="${titles_ALL}")}

When I run the script for all the cases this condition is passing so apple folder title is also being compared with cherry and condition is becoming true and proceeding further. I only want apple to apple comparison to pass( 1 on 1).

I am thinking that title and titles values are not picked up properly inside the for each controller, but I used the correct json extractor because out side the foreach controller I have used the bean shell assertion and compared them all the values are picking up properly.

json extractor used details for title variable:
variable: title
path: $..title
match no :-1
checked the suffix_ALL box

In same way used for titles as well.

Please help me out!! why is the condition not failing when title and titles are different values.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the following [JMeter Variables](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html) defined:

```
title_ALL={apple, pineapple, blue berry, cherry}
titles_ALL={apple, blue berry, cherry, pineapple, kiwi}
```

your expression in the If Controller will never be true as the values are not the same.

If you want to compare them one by one you should rather be comparing `${title_1}` to `${titles_1}`, `${title_2}` to `${titles_2}`, etc.

Example expression:

```
${__jexl3("${title}"=="${__V(titles_${__intSum(${__jm__ForEach Controller__idx},1,)},)}",)}
```

You can use a [Debug Sampler and View Results Tree listener combination](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-debug-your-apache-jmeter-script) to see the current values of the variables.

If in case of match you don't want to continue the comparison and would like to proceed to the next iteration or get out from the ForEach Loop - take a look at [Flow Control Action Sampler](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Flow_Control_Action)

[image]

Small demo:

[image]